# Mechanics for non-standard shapes

Tags: classical-mechanics, stress-strain

The question I have arose when I was working my way through a derivation of the relationship between Young's Modulus, Poisson's ratio and the Shear Modulus (modulus of rigidity),
\begin{align}
 G = \frac{E}{2(1+\nu)} .
\end{align}
This derivation can be found here: http://www.philiphofmann.net/book_material/notes/elastic_constants2.pdf

So at some point they sort of spin a cube 45 degrees, embed it in a bigger - imaginary - cuboid, and apply a force to the top face of this cuboid. Then to find the stress they divide the force by the area of the top face of this cuboid. What I don't understand is, we are actually pulling on an edge of the small cube here. The way the stress is then computed doesnt seem obvious to me. Following this reasoning, it kind of seems that generally, when applying a force on an object, the resulting stress could be found by dividing this force by the largest area of a cross section along the direction of the force. Could anyone clarify this?

I guess, more generally, my question is:
Say you have a force that is not necessarily perpendicular to a face of not necessarily a cuboid. What would be the resulting stress (and strain)? Worded differently: If you apply a force in an arbitrary direction, at an arbitrary point of an arbitrary object, what would be the resulting stress (and strain)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Find your favorite mechanical engineering finite element analysis package. In general this is a really hard problem, more so if the body is a single crystal low symmetry material.

Comment: As a simpler example, find a strength of materials textbook and read the chapter about stresses and strains in cantilever beams. Your "kind of seems that" assumption is only true when the stress field is uniform, which what your PDF reference is assuming. In other words the "force F" in the diagrams is *distributed* evenly over the whole face of the cube, not applied at one point.

Comment: So is this what you're saying: force $F$ distributed evenly over the top face of the cuboid results in the same stress and strain as force $F$ applied to the top edge of the embedded cube?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Cauchy Stress Relationship (aka Cauchy's Law)?